# How to publish docker port from GitLab CI docker runner

Tags: docker, selenium-grid, gitlab-ci

I have a Selenium Grid server with some nodes and one node is windows machine with IE11.
  In my gradle build I've defined task with FE build and in this task I'm running some FE tests with karma. So I need to connect karma server to selenium grid with port 9876.
But, in GitLab CI I have no option to bind (or expose) any port, so I'm not able to connect to my Selenium Grid Hub and build fails.

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
image: gradle

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle --build-cache --stacktrace clean :gradle-project:buildFrontend
```

build.gradle:

```
task buildFrontend(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
    args = ["run", "build:prod"] // executes npm run build:prod
}
```

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
   "build": "webpack --progress",
   "build:prod": "karma start test/karma.conf.js && webpack --env production --progress",
   "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js"
 }
```

Build Environment:

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue right now. If I figure something out I will let you know.

Comment: Are you in control of the gitlab runner server?

Comment: Yes, I'm admin of runner server

Comment: In my case all container where running on the same docker host, so that I was able to create shared network for all the running container.

First I created the network `docker network create outside`, than added it to all my Selenium Docker container and used 
`network_mode` in gitlab-runner config.toml file to add the outside network to my runner.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section

Comment: @synk , Thanks to suggestion. So now I have gradle and selenium hub and docker nodes in `selenium-grid` network and it works fine, but I still have problem with connecting to IE11 node, because IE wants make request to server with port 9876. Server is running in gradle container, but this container have not open port 9876, so request is not success. I attaching my environment configuration [in image](https://i.imgur.com/7QHKj5f.png)